# Do you capitalize a job title when speaking in 1st person?

Tags: capitalization

Would you capitalize a job title if you were to write "As an experienced web designer".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should "Project Manager" be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/should-project-manager-be-capitalized)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No capital here:

> as an experienced web designer

Capital here:

> as Supervisor of Web Design

assuming that was the title of your position