# Are the words "Senator" and "Representative" capitalized in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, capitalization

In the following sentence are the words "senator and "representative" capitalized?

There are many special restrictions that senators and representatives must abide by.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Capitalization of titles is largely a matter of style; see *[Understanding U.S. President capitalization](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44848/)* and *[Should “Project Manager” be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1393)* for example.

Comment: I disagree that the linked question is a duplicate.  If it is truly an issue of style, then this question provides utility to the community by simply opening a space in which specific examples of stylistic choices (such as the one below) can be shown.  Someone with the same question led here by a google search will not be helped by the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look at wikipedia reveals the answer: No.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Congress

"Senate" and "House of Representatives" are capitalized but the roles themselves are not, eg: *"Both senators and representatives are chosen through direct election"*