# Question of capitalization of a word

Tags: capitalization

Which is correct:

> I have been asked by **attorney Smith** to inspect the documents.

or

> I have been asked by **Attorney Smith** to inspect the documents.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We cannot give you an answer without additional context, and some indication as to what you found lacking in your initial research. Is *Attorney* a title? What style manual are you following? Also see *[Should “Project Manager” be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1393)* and *[Understanding U.S. President capitalization](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44848/)* among others.

Answer (score 0):

Neither! In the US, if Mr. Smith is the US federal or a state Attorney General then you may use **Attorney General Smith**. If you have been asked by a lawyer to inspect documents (presumably in an lawyer-client situation) then you should write, "I have been asked by my/his/their attorney to inspect the documents".

Comment: In a formal written Attorney Smith would be correct.